# Ignore WCF certificate errors in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf

I have a solution like this :

```
-MySolution
|--MyWCFWrapper
|--MyaspnetcoreWebApp
|--ConsoleTestApp
```

`MyWCFWrapper` is a .NET Standard library consumes the WCF service added as a WCF reference using the Visual Studio import wizard.

The `MyaspnetcoreWebApp` application provides controllers for a front end to consume. In this controller, I am instantiating and making calls to `MyWCFWrapper` library.

The `ConsoleTestApp` is a console application that also makes calls to `MyWCFWrapper` library for testing.

I get an error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: 'Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'exampleabc.com'

when I make WCF service calls.

The reason for this error is my WCF service at exampleablc.com is a test server and has a self signed certificate (name different to the webservice) and is also **expired**.

Workaround that works in ConsoleTestApp :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
    {
        return true;
    };
MyWCFWrapperClass api = new MyWCFWrapperClass(..);
api.SendNewInfo("NewInfo");
```

This is **not recommended**, but this is ok for me for now because it's a test server.

The same workaround does not work in the MyaspnetcoreWebApp controller. What I have tried to make it work :.

- In `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient("SeitaCertificate").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request, certificate, certificateChain, policy) =>
            {
                return true;
            }
        };
    });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    ----
}
```

- Added the certificate to Trusted Root Certificate Authorities on my local PC. This fails probably because the certificate has expired.

The certificate error is raised in the WCF call library and I have not been able to find a way to ignore the cert error.
What I can do is at least have the certificate updated so that it is not expired. (I have started this process and it is likely to take some time)

I would like to learn a way how to capture and ignore these certificate errors selectively and appropriately for calling a WCF library in a asp .net core 3.1 web application. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can refer to the following code to bypass certificate verification:

```
            BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));

            factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new System.ServiceModel.Security.X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
            {
                CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
                RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
            };
```

Comment: I used the svcutil (VS add WCF reference) to create Reference.cs class. In that case, its easier to just modify the constructor of Client it created and use ChannelFactory of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue by overriding the certificate validation method [X509CertificateValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.selectors.x509certificatevalidator?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new YourServiceReference.Cient();

        // Bypass certificate verification
        client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication
        {
            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom,
            CustomCertificateValidator = new CustomCertificateValidator()
        };

        // --------
    }

    internal class CustomCertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
    {
        // Override certificate validation
        public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is asked more than a years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer