SSRS ReportingService2010SoapClient SSL/TLS error
Trying to call function GetItemParametersAsync from an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API running inside a container on Linux, but I get this error

One or more errors occurred (Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority)

But it does work when I run it from my local machine. Errors out only when I push the code to container. And I did verify credentials and SSL certificate.
This code to get report parameters throws above mentioned error:
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
rsReporting = new ReportingService2010SoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(SSRSServerUrl));
var clientCredentials = new NetworkCredential(User, Password, Domain);
rsReporting.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
rsReporting.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = clientCredentials;
rsReporting.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(SSRSReport2010);
var parameters = rsReporting.GetItemParametersAsync(trustedUserHeader, reportPath, historyId, forRendering, values, credentials);
foreach (ItemParameter param in parameters.Result.Parameters)
{
   ReportParams.Add(param.Name, param.DefaultValues[0]);
}

However, I'm able to access report catalog using below code on same ssrs server from same ASP.NET Core Web API running inside a container.
This code to get report catalog items works:
string requestUrl = $"reports/api/v2.0/CatalogItems";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

I'm using same url and credentials for both the above methods.

Hi @Shankar Naru, for this error message, it seems  the container is unable to trust the SSL certificate of the SSRS server. You could try the steps: 1.verify that the container trusts the certificate authority (CA) used by the SSRS server. 2.Ensure that your binding is using a modern SSL/TLS version (e.g., TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3). 3.Ensure that the container has access to the root CA certificate or the server's SSL certificate itself.

Thank you Rena! The solution mentioned here worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655500/ignore-wcf-certificate-errors-in-asp-net-core-3-1
